# How to check if string contains value in EpiFind?

Tags: c#, episerver, episerver-find

I want to check if indexed string (my case string is "1,2,3") contains some value (like an actual string.Contains method), but it seems like **EpiFind** doesn't supply method for that.

I applied value.AnyWordBeginsWith(match) and it seems to work in my case but it's a hacky solution and might fail

```
searchQuery.Filter(x => x.StringToCheck.AnyWordBeginsWith("2"));
```

Is there a proper way to check if string contains my value?

Like this:

```
searchQuery.Filter(x => x.StringToCheck.Contains("2"));
```

Please note that **this question is not related to ordinary string comparison in C# or LINQ** before flagging the question.

Comment: Hi @Ivan , I think this [link](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Find/11/DotNET-Client-API/Searching/Filtering/Strings/) and [this one](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/EPiServer-Find/8/DotNET-Client-API/Searching/Searching/) will solve your problem, if you need help please contact me

Comment: Do you use the unified search or the typed search?

Comment: @EricHerlitz I use ITypeSearch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably opt to [index that value as a string array](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/EPiServer-Search/Thread-Container/2018/7/filterbuilder-question-matching-comma-seperated-string-with-a-list/) instead. It will simplify searching/filtering.

To do that, simply add a helper property like...

```
// Helper property used for indexing
public string[] ArrayOfStringToCheck => return StringToCheck?.Split(',');
```

...and then reindex your content. After that you can filter like:

`searchQuery.Filter(x => x.ArrayOfStringToCheck.Match("stringToFind"));`

Comment: That hack will probably work but not better than AnyWordBeginsWith and still will hit something like 12 when searching for 2

Comment: AnyWordBeginsWith sounds risky as it could match values _beginning_ with "2", not equal to "2"?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm not going to use it

Comment: Right, my point was just that the hack is better since it doesn't risk such incorrect matches. :)

Comment: I'm trying to do `searchQuery.Filter(x => "2".In(x.SplittedString))` but debugger throws InvalidOperationException saying that x is out of scope (here - `x.SplittedString`). What could it be?

Comment: Ah, x should be on the left side of DelegateFilterBuilder expression

Comment: So it goes like this: you add new prop to your content: `IEnumerable<string> SplittedString => StringToCheck.Split(',');`. Reindex it. Then filter will be `searchQuery.Filter(x => x.SplittedString.Match(valueToFind));`. It searches in array instead of string. If you add this to your answer I will mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: @IvanMaslov Done. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, why `.In(...`? It's for when you have string on the left and array on the right. If it's opposite, then you use `.Match(...` At least it works for me like this in Epifind 13.0.1

Comment: @IvanMaslov Doh, you're right, some copy-and-paste error there I think. :) Changed it to `Match`.